# xml fails when using SSL https request

Tags: javascript, xml, perl

I have the following javascript that works fine when http is used but not https from IE 11.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function checkloginform() {
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
       xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   } else {
       xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // code for IE6, IE5
   }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
         var y = xmlhttp.responseText;
         document.getElementById("memo").innerHTML = y;
     } else {
         document.getElementById("memo").innerHTML =
          'Error: '+ xmlhttp.readyState + ' ' + xmlhttp.status;
     }
   }
   xmlhttp.open("GET","/test/test.pl",true);
   xmlhttp.send();
 }
</script>
```

if I change

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","/test/test.pl",true);
```

to

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","https://www.website.com/test/test.pl",true);
```

I get nothing back and no status errors?

If I access the url directly from the same browser it does return the expected output.

here is the server side test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

MAIN:
{
 print qq~content-type: text/xml\n\nTEST\n ~;
 exit;
}
```

Comment: Do the logs on the web server show `test.pl` being served?

Comment: To get it to work I changed the initial link that serves the above javascript from `<a href="http://www.website.com/test/">TEST</a>` to `<a href="https://www.website.com/test/">TEST</a>;`. Not sure why but all references need to stay within https or all within http. ???

Comment: The more I read this may have been a cross domain issue.

Answer (score 0):

This was do to a cross domain issues. I loaded the site via http @ xyz.com and switched to https @ 123.com.